# Receive data of variable size in asynchronous socket communication in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets, asynchronous, udp

I am making an application in c#.In that application I am using asynchronous socket communication.I have written code as

```
byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];
clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref m_EpReceive, new AsyncCallback(OnRceiveCallBack), objReceiverSocketState);
```

Here I am getting `byteData` of variable size means sometime 700 bytes,sometime 276 byte (not fixed). Here I have declared `byteData`  of 1024 size. So my question is that is there any way which can declare the size of `byteData`  to exact amount of data received? (Means suppose i am getting 500 bytes so the size of `byteData`  should be 500.) I also have question that if I have declared size of `byteData` to 1024 so whether it will wait to get total 1024 bytes or if it got some bytes then  it will call the `OnRceiveCallBack` method? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EndReceiveFrom` will tell you how much bytes has been been received.

```
public int EndReceiveFrom(
      IAsyncResult asyncResult,
      ref EndPoint endPoint
  )
```

As MSDN says :

> Return Value
>  Type: System.Int32  
> If successful, the number of bytes
>   received. If unsuccessful, returns 0.